# cx_Freeze - The appdirs package is required

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I`m trying to convert a .py script to an .exe

cx_Freeze compiles the exe succesfully. However when I run the exe file it throws this error:

> ImportError: The 'appdirs' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution

Here is my setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "dbx_sharelink" ,
    version = "0.1" ,
    description = " " ,
    executables = [Executable("dbx_sharelink.py")]  ,
)
```

Source code Python script

```
import sys
import dropbox
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

def getSharedLink(full_path):
    try:
        link = dbx.sharing_create_shared_link(full_path).url
    except dropbox.exceptions.ApiError as err:
        print('*** API error', err)
        return None
    return link


print(sys.argv[1])
link = getSharedLink("/A_DATA/data")

df = pd.DataFrame([{'link':link}])
df.to_clipboard(index=False,header=False)


os.system("pause")
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you share the Python script that you are trying to freeze?

Comment: I added the source code to my question now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same problem..
Add **options** parameter to the setup.py file like this:

```
setup (name="MyAPP",
       version="0.1",
       description = "My GUI application!",
       options = {'build_exe': {'packages':packages}},
       .
       .
       .)
```

under packages put(**packages should come before the setup**):

```
packages = ['pkg_resources._vendor']
```

(you can add more packages if you have similar problems like this one..)

you can read more on the options here: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe

**This solved the problem for me!**

---

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Just add the packages to the options

```
additional_mods = ['appdirs', 'packaging.version']
additional_packages = ['scipy', 'numpy', 'appdirs', 'packaging']

options = {
        'build_exe': {
                      'packages': additional_packages,
                      'includes': additional_mods,
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying upgrading to setuptools 34.4.1, this worked for me

Comment: This didn't work on python 3.6.1 on linux for me, setuptools doesn't depend on appdirs.  cx_freeze also doesn't install appdirs as a dependency with pip3.